# React not setting hook state despite using hook setter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a search bar input:

```
      <input
          type="text"
          className="px-4 py-2 w-80"
          placeholder="Search"
          onChange={(event) => searchWord(event.target.value)}
        />
```

I have this set up at the top of my file:

```
  const [foundWords, setFoundWords] = useState<any>([]);
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState('');

  const fetchWords = async () => {
    console.log("1", searchString);
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/find?searchString=${searchString.toLowerCase()}`)
      .then(({ data }) => setFoundWords(data));
  }

  const debounce = (fn: Function, ms = 300) => {
    let timeoutId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
    return function (this: any, ...args: any[]) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, args), ms);
    };
  };

  const searchWord = debounce((input: string) => {
    console.log("2", input)
    setSearchString(input);
    if (!input) return;
    fetchWords()
  }, 500);
```

The console log "1" above returns an empty string, but the console log "2" returns my search query.

What's going wrong with it?

Comment: I have suspition, that this is caused because fetchWords is async... try to comment axios call and removing async if it helps... maybe wrapping this function in useCallbeck with searchString as dependency... but in this case, passing searchString as parameter when calling this function will looks better in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `useEffect` instead of directly calling the `fetchWords` from the `searchWord` function

I would update your code the following way

```
  const [foundWords, setFoundWords] = useState<any>([]);
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState('');

  const fetchWords = useCallback((input: string) => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/find?searchString=${input.toLowerCase()}`)
      .then(({ data }) => setFoundWords(data));
  }, [])

  const debounce = (fn: Function, ms = 300) => {
    let timeoutId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
    return function (this: any, ...args: any[]) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, args), ms);
    };
  };

  const searchWord = debounce((input: string) => {
    setSearchString(input);
  }, 500)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchString) {
      fetchWords(searchString)
    }
  }, [searchString, fetchWords])
```

UseEffect would be guaranteed to trigger only after the searchString is updated. And as per `useCallback` for `fetchWords`. It is a better optimization and a good practice for functions used inside `useEffect` to be wrapped inside `useCallback`

Also, you can further optimize your code in the following way if it is not required to trigger render cycle again on change of `searchString`.

```
  const [foundWords, setFoundWords] = useState<any>([]);

  const fetchWords = useCallback((input: string) => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/find?searchString=${input.toLowerCase()}`)
      .then(({ data }) => setFoundWords(data));
  }, [])

  const debounce = (fn: Function, ms = 300) => {
    let timeoutId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
    return function (this: any, ...args: any[]) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, args), ms);
    };
  };

  const searchWord = debounce((input: string) => {
    if (input) {
      fetchWords(input)
    }
  }, 500)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! I'm keen to preserve the search string since I want to be able to grab that from URL params if directly linked to. though guess I don't strictly need local state for that